# Reset a user's password (in the AspNetUsers table) using SQL only

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

Is there a way to reset a user's password (in the AspNetUsers table) using SQL only? I am using ASP.NET Identity (Forms Authentication) in MVC 5.

Comment: You're talking about SQL query or EF way?

Comment: Strictly SQL query (not using EF)

Comment: Try use Update script. in a moment I'll write answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add some simple user and get users Password hash and security stamp, next use SQL query like this:

```
USE [Your database name]
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[Users]
SET [UserId] = <UserId, nvarchar(128),>
  ,[Email] = <Email, nvarchar(256),>
  ,[EmailConfirmed] = <EmailConfirmed, bit,>
  ,[PasswordHash] = <PasswordHash, nvarchar(max),> // Your password here
  ,[SecurityStamp] = <SecurityStamp, nvarchar(max),> // Security stamp here
  ,[PhoneNumber] = <PhoneNumber, nvarchar(max),>
  ,[PhoneNumberConfirmed] = <PhoneNumberConfirmed, bit,>
  ,[TwoFactorEnabled] = <TwoFactorEnabled, bit,>
  ,[LockoutEndDateUtc] = <LockoutEndDateUtc, datetime,>
  ,[LockoutEnabled] = <LockoutEnabled, bit,>
  ,[AccessFailedCount] = <AccessFailedCount, int,>
  ,[UserName] = <UserName, nvarchar(256),>
  ,[Discriminator] = <Discriminator, nvarchar(128),>
  WHERE <Search Conditions,,> // here place Your user Id
  GO
```

So your user password will be updated.

Comment: this shows some syntax error

Comment: On which line ?@EngrUmair

Comment: <UserId, nvarchar(128),>

Comment: @EngrUmair if you're using integers as id you'll receive an error, it's good idea if you share bit more information, SQL server type, table data example etc.

Comment: I have tried the following but it stores in chine's :
Update dbo.AspNetUsers
 set dbo.AspNetUsers.PasswordHash = HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'abc233')
you can also answer on my post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71605922/update-aspnetusers-table-password-with-sql-only